# How to calculate the density of color glass condensate

Tags: particle-physics

[Color glass condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color-glass_condensate) is theoretical type of matter that is supposed to exist in the nuclei of relativistic particles. Now, the name itself implies that the material is very dense, but how can we calculate this density?

Comment: What kind of density? Mass/energy density? Gluon number density?

Comment: The former, mass/energy density.